# Webpack with Nextjs for worker-loader package

Tags: webpack, next.js

Following [this page](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/custom-webpack-config), I've set up my config as follows:

```
require('dotenv').config()

module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, webpack }) => {

    config.output.globalObject = 'this'
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.worker\.js$/,
      use: { loader: 'worker-loader' }
    })

    return config
  },
}
```

However, when I run `yarn run build`, I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: Worker is not defined
```

It really looks like the webpack setup isn't done properly. Anyone ran into a similar issue?

Comment: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/10899 try this npm install worker-loader @zeit/next-workers